# concatenate values within APEX Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, string

I am have trouble with line breaks and string literals:

I cannot get the below to compile:

```
newD.Additional_Information__c = recTypeName +  '\r\n\r\n' 
                            + recTypeName == 'Data Request' ? rq.Reason_for_data_request__c :  rq.Reason_for_mailshot__c + ' \r\n'
                            + '\r\n\' + 'Pre-Extract Systems Analysis ' + rq.Systems_analysis__c;
```

what I want is to add a line break into the field but I am getting the error on this line:

```
+ '\r\n\' + 'Pre-Extract Systems Analysis ' + rq.Systems_analysis__c;
```

The error is `Save error: line breaks not allowed in string literals`

What is the correct or best way to include line breaks in strings within my fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
+ '\r\n\' + 'Pre-Extract Systems Analysis ' + rq.Systems_analysis__c;
```

contains a `\'` which is escaping the close `'` and screwing everything up for you. It looks like it should just be:

```
+ '\r\n' + 'Pre-Extract Systems Analysis ' + rq.Systems_analysis__c;
```

or if you need that final slash

```
+ '\r\n\\' + 'Pre-Extract Systems Analysis ' + rq.Systems_analysis__c;
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is on that line you're trying to add. `\'` is an escaped quote character, meaning your string isn't properly closed. simply removing the `\` should fix the problem.